# Directional moment vanishing conditions and Fourier transform

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-transform

In ["The Contourlet Transform: An Efficient Directional Multiresolution Image Representation" by Minh N. Do and Martin Vetterli](http://minhdo.ece.illinois.edu/publications/contourlet_txform.pdf) on page 10 it says:

> **Definition.** A $2D$-function $\lambda(t)$ is said to have an $L$-th order vanishing moment in the direction $u = (u_1, u_2)^T$ if all $1D$-slices of that function along the direction $u$, $\lambda_{u, r_2}(r_1) = \lambda(r_1 u + r_2 u^{\perp})$, where $u^{\perp} = (- u_2, u_1)^T$ have $L$ vanishing moments:
>   $$ \tag{1}
> \int_{\mathbb{R}} \lambda_{u,r_2}(r_1) r_1^p d r_1 = 0 \quad \forall r_2 \in \mathbb{R}, \ \forall p \in \{0, \ldots, L - 1\}.
> $$
>
> It can be shown that in the Fourier domain the DVM condition $(1)$ is equivalent to requiring $\Lambda(\omega_1,\omega_2)$ and its $L - 1$ first derivatives in the direction $u$ to be zero along the line $u_1 \omega_1 + u_2 \omega_2 = 0$.

I am interested in a reference for the proof of the statement above or even better a *hint on how to prove the following special case*:

*Problem.* Let $\psi: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be compactly supported and for a fixed $\xi_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ fulfill $$\hat{\psi}(0, \xi_2) = \frac{\partial \hat{\psi}}{\partial \xi_1}(0, \xi_2) = 0.$$
Then $\int_{\mathbb{R}} x_1^k \psi(x_1, x_2) d x_1 = 0$ holds for all $x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $k \in \{0,1\}$.

---

In this problem, $L = 2$, $u = (1,0)^T$, therefore $\psi_{u,r_2}(r_1) = \psi(r_1, r_2)$.

Comment: huh? the case $k=0$ is definition of $\hat{\psi}(0,\xi_2)$. the case $k=1$ is standard fact that fourier transform of product is derivative of fourier transform, but I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: @mathworker But isn't $\hat{\psi}(0,\xi_2) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \psi(0,x_2) e^{- i \xi_2 x_2} d x_2$?. Also, I am not aware of the second fact you mention. Could you please write it out so I can try to prove it?

Comment: I'll check the equation you wrote later. the second fact should literally just be $\frac{\partial \hat{\psi}}{\partial \xi_1}(0, \xi_2) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} x_1 \psi(x_1, x_2) d x_1$, one of the most basic properties of the fourier transform.

Comment: @mathworker unfortunately I haven't been able to figure this property out, I will soon post my attempts into the question body.